# What does the Enchantment Vorpal do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I just enchanted a book. Now it has "Vorpal II" on it and I don't know what this enchantment does. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you using the FTB modpack?

Comment: nope - some custom mods on our own server. Among those is rp2.

Comment: The name comes from [Jabberwocky by Lewis Carroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky) and specifically the fifth verse - "One, two! One, two! and through and through / The vorpal blade went snicker-snack! / He left it dead, and with its head / He went galumphing back."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Redpower2 mod for Minecraft removes the default chance of a mob dropping its head, and instead adds the Vorpal enchantment. When killed with a Vorpal enchanted weapon, mobs and players have a chance to drop their head, increasing with a higher Vorpal level. Unfortunately, this affect does not work on wither skeletons. The Vorpal enchantment also gives a chance for your attack to deal a large amount of damage.

Answer (score 7):

Vorpal Enchantment: (RP2)

Type: Weapon

Vorpal Levels: 1-4
; Each rank increases the likelihood of the effect.

Effect: Beheads the enemy, killing the player or mob and dropping their head. Does not seem to affect Wither Skeletons. Note that this is a 1-shot kill chance and is a powerful enchant.

Answer (score 3):

It increases the chances that a mob drops its head. It comes from the RedPower2 mod.